# What does "2..xxx" mean in shaderlab?

Tags: unity-game-engine, shaderlab

```
float3 f = float3(1,2,3);
f *= 2..xxx;
```

I have no idea what ..xxx does. I got the code from [here](https://forum.unity.com/threads/how-to-draw-many-circles-efficiently.770000/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a "swizzle" operation. In this case of a scalar constant 2.0.
`2..xxx` is equivalent to `float3(2.0, 2.0, 2.0)`

You can find more info [here](https://developer.download.nvidia.com/cg/Cg_language.html) in the "Vector swizzle operator" section.